# Looping when using node js require()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Currently i have define require file as below.

```
constantPath = './config/file/'

fileAA = require(path.resolve(constantPath + 'A-A')),
fileBB = require(path.resolve(constantPath + 'B-B')),
fileCC = require(path.resolve(constantPath + 'C-C')),
....
....
```

It is notice that all the path is of same path and the require variable is of the similar of file name.
I would not like to repeat this procedure x number of times as it violates the DRY principle 
Is it possible to have foreach loop here. Eg: Read all file in the folder dynamically and use require to assign it?

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the answer by [BradyCartmell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35401146/1690108), but a bit neater;

```
var fs = require('fs');

var constantPath = './config/file/';
var files = { };

fs.readdir(constantPath, function(err, modules) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  modules
    .filter(function (module) {
      return module.slice(module.length - 3) === '.js';
    })
    .forEach(function (module) {
      files[module] = require(constantPath + module);
    });
});
```

Noted differences;

- I don't think you have to trim the ".js" when calling `require`
- Store in a files object, rather than globally... that is gross

**Note:** Please be aware this is asynchronous, and so please write the rest of your code appropriately (i.e. trigger it running from inside the `fs.readdir` callback.

For completeness, if you'd like a synchronous version to avoid bothering with that;

```
var fs = require('fs');

var constantPath = './config/file/';
var files = { };

fs.readdirSync(constantPath)
  .filter(function (module) {
    return module.slice(module.length - 3) === '.js';
  })
  .forEach(function (module) {
    files[module] = require(constantPath + module);
  });
```

Comment: Yes, storing it on global feels gross, but it creates the same result as the code in the original question and that of typical require usage.  Good call on using the sync version and dropping the .js slice.

Comment: @BradyCartmell technically, you're right. But I imagine the OP just left out `var` declarations, which make it slightly different to `global`. ;)

Answer (score 2):

If every file of that folder is meant to be required as a script, you probably want something that explicitly requires all files.

It's possible with the node module [require-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-all).

**NodeJS:**

```
require('require-all')(__dirname + '/config/file/');
```

---

You can also use module [require-dir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-dir).

**NodeJS:**

```
require('require-dir')('./config/file');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: let say i use `var a = require('require-all');` How could i specific which file i am using in the code?

Comment: Hi, you can use it with `filter`, you can refer to examples of usage: https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-all

Comment: I think i did not elaborate clearly. Assume that `var a = require('require-all')(__dirname + '/config/file/');` will have all the json file be required. Now suppose that i would like to use the json of the file with name "country.json" in a, how could it be done?

Comment: @vincentsty The `filter` option allows you to use a regular expression. That means you can use generic patterns and specific file names as well into it with "ORs" in the expression. However, for those specific files, it can be more readable to reach them in specific file queries. Does it make sense?

Comment: I am getting confused. Suppose that var a now includes file1.json, file2.json and file3.json after require-all. How can i access file2.json specifically in my code?

Comment: Please read the documentation on `require-all`, where it says: "an object with references to all modules matching the filter"

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require('fs');

var modsDir = './mods/dir';
fs.readdir(modsDir, (err, fileNames) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  fileNames.forEach((fileName) => {
    if (fileName.slice(fileName.length-3) === '.js') {
      fileName = fileName.slice(0, fileName.length-3);

      // This feels dirty
      global[fileName] = require(modsDir+fileName);

    }
  });
});
```

Should probably be encapsulated to isolate modsDir, but this shows the gist of it anyway.